# Invalid 'Podfile' file

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to pod update, but am getting this error

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Cannot set inheritance for abstract target  definition

about

```
target 'Project-IntegrationTests'
inherit! :search_paths
pod 'OCMock', '= 3.1.2'
```

Comment: You can try running "pod init" in your project folder and then try adding pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

def testPods
  pod 'OCMock', '= 3.1.2'
end

target 'Project-IntegrationTests' do
  testPods
end
```

Not all flags are mandatory.